# Parse csv file with special character like µ using java

Tags: java, csv, parsing, unicode, special-characters

I have a situation where I have to read a CSV file which contains special character like 'µ'. This has to be done using java. I am doing:
*BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(,"UTF-8"));*

in windows it runs OK. But in redhat linux environment, it converts those special characters to '?'. Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Double check the actual encoding of the file being read. The binary contents matter.

Comment: Maybe the file is not encoded `UTF-8`

Comment: File encoding is "UTF-8". Checked that multiple times. Locale of the linux machine is "UTF-8"

Comment: How do you check what they reader is returning? It's possible that the file is read correctly but there's a problem with how it's displayed

Comment: First of all check if you write correctly your csv, see if your 'µ' is encoded correctly to UTF-8, and is not taken from extended ASCII which is very dependent on code conversion pages. You have to debug your application and see the exact UNICODE value of the character you get from the CSV. Also there is the second case: check if there is any conversion from/to UNICODE to byte. Debug your program and provide the exact information where it happens and see if it is the case. You have to spot that location and make changes in such a way that no UNICODE to ASCII conversion happens.

Comment: Just after it reads when I print, it shows those special characters as '?'. So whether it reads properly or not that is not important. I need to get proper result out of that

Comment: By printing do you mean showing text in a console or using a printer to write the text on a piece of paper? Can you share the code that prints?

Comment: Its just a System.out.println. It shows '?' in console.

Answer (score 1):

Output written to `System.out` will be encoded using the "platform default encoding" which on linux is determined from locale environment variables (see output of `locale` command), and those in turn are set in user or system level configuration files.

On server installations, the default encoding is often `ASCII`. "µ" is not an ASCII character so it will be converted to "?" when it is printed.

There are a couple of ways to change the default encoding:

- Set the Java `file.encoding` system property when you run your program, e.g.

  ```
  java -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 yourprogram
  ```
- Set LC_CTYPE env variable before you run your program, for example:

  ```
  export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
  java yourprogram
  ```
- Those methods also change the default encoding for input and file names etc. You can change the encoding specifically for `System.out` with Java code:

  ```
  PrintStream originalOut = System.out; // in case you need it later
  System.setOut(new PrintStream(System.out, true, "utf-8"));
  ```

Comment: Hi Joni ... thanks for your reply. I tried your suggestions. It runs in Windows, but still fails in linux environment

Comment: Try writing a program that only prints µ and does nothing else: `public static void main(String... args) { System.out.println("\u00b5"); }` See if that works. If it does, the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Why \u00b5 ? I am trying to parse symbols not ASCII to characters

Comment: It's an escape code that the compiler will replace with "µ" . It's guaranteed to work no matter what text encoding you use for the source file. If you write "µ" in source code there's a chance the compiler will not interpret it correctly